# rsocket after upgrade to 1.0.2 client stop to receive answer

Tags: java, rsocket

Client code:

```
   clientRSocket = RSocketConnector.create()
                    .metadataMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.getString())
                    .payloadDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
                    //.reconnect(Retry.backoff(50, Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                    .dataMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
                    .resume(new Resume().sessionDuration(getLocalConfig().getDuration("resumeDurationInMinutes"))
                            .retry(Retry.fixedDelay(Long.MAX_VALUE, getLocalConfig().getDuration("fixedDelayInSeconds")))
                    .streamTimeout(getLocalConfig().getDuration("resumeTimeOutInSeconds")))
                    .connect(TcpClientTransport.create(getLocalConfig().getInt("port")))
                    .doOnError(exception -> getLogger().error(DaeLogKeys.rsocket.failed.error, exception))
                    .block();
```

**example to client stream request:**

```
rsocket.requestStream(DefaultPayload.create(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.buffer(),
                socket.route(List.of("part-type.getAll"))))
                .map(Payload::getDataUtf8)
                .map(doc->socket.decode(doc,DaeApiPartType.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()).block())
```

**example for server response:**

```
@MessageMapping("part-type.getAll")
    public Flux<DaeApiPartType> getAllPartTypes() {
        return controlPartType.findAll();
    }
```

It's seems that everything is going well. I see the client release payload but nothing is getting back. No errors. Client is stuck and waiting for answer.

At 1.0.1 this example worked.
Please advise.